# Is there another way besides "all" to check if all elements values before my target element are true?

Tags: python

I'm trying to return true if only all the previous elements are true up to the current position.

I have it set up with `all` function but I don't want to code it this way

```
        def check(lightsOnOff, light):
        for light in lights[:light]:
            if not on:
                return False
        return True

        count = count + 1
```

Comment: Yes, just implement `all` yourself. Do you understand the logic? Note, it would really help if you provided a [mcve]

Comment: Hard to understand what's going on there. First, you have a dict `lightsOnOff`, then you create a list out of its values? Dict does not preserve order so what you are doing there with up to index light will not work.

Comment: They're ordered in 3.6+. This code looks fine, and I don't understand why OP doesn't want to use it. You can use `itertools.takewhile` or something and check that the length matches but this seems like hammering a nail with a screwdriver.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Why don't you want to use `all`? Please [edit] to clarify. You might want to read [ask].

Comment: i understand that the "all" function will return true if and only if all elements are true, and no i don't really know how to implement it.

Comment: `for item in it: if not item return False` and add `return True` at the end of the loop. That's all [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) is.

Answer (score 1):

In general `all` is a useful construct to use, I can see why it looks wrong in this expression

```
all(list(lightsOnOff.values())[:light])
```

but the smelly part is actually the `list(iterable)[:number]` construction, which forces construction of the whole list then truncates it.

**As an important aside, if `lightsOnOff` is a `dict` (not e.g. an `OrderedDict`) your code will be non-deterministic (see notes at bottom).**

If you don't want to create a list and slice it, you can leverage itertools:

```
from itertools import islince 
   ...
all(islice(lightsOnOff.values(), n))
```

---

As a frame challenge, if your dict has an order and you know the keys, you can simply rewrite it as:

```
all(lightsOnOff[k] for k in keys[:light])
```

and if your dict has keys that are ordered and e.g. integers, just use a list?

```
all(listOfLights[:light])
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you want to implement `all` yourself on an arbitrary list, you can do something like:

```
my_list = [1, 7, 2, 1, None, 2, 3]
up_to_ix = 5

def my_all(some_list, up_to_index):
    for element in some_list[:up_to_index]:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True

my_all(my_list, up_to_ix)
```

The function will loop through all elements in the list up to, but excluding the `some_index` and if it finds at least one `Falsy` value, will return `False`, otherwise `True`.